# Should I use OAuth/OAuth2 for SOA type web services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, soa, oauth-2.0

My company is making a product where we have both a front and backend. The backend essentially provides all the brains as far as user information. The front end is something that will be displayed to the user (obviously), but if may have different front end implementations (including our own reference implementation).

My company wants to use OAuth to validate the user login information. I've looked into OAuth a bit and it seems that OAuth 1 would require the user to post a key into the front end app. Does that at all sound right? It seems a little contrived to me because all the data resides on the backend. We really just want to verify that the front end is from a legit 3rd party. Is OAuth overkill for that? Would OAuth 2 be a better fit?

Keep in mind in working with Ruby on Rails and so I'm not sure how great the OAuth2 gemsets are.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth might be an overkill if you are only using it internally. However since you're implementation would just be a reference design and you expect 3rd parties to connect it seems a good decision to rely on a standard.

As ruby implementations goes - you probably want to look at [oauth-plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/tree/rails3) (on the rails side) and [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) (client) gems

Comment: I think what I'm concerned about is that I don't want the end user to have to copy and paste tokens. That doesn't seem to make much sense for the type of product we are using since essentially it's all internal.

Comment: if it is just internal why do you need the any type of enforcement?

Comment: regardless of why - if it is just internal you can do whatever is more convenient for you and later if/when it will become public add a more standard authorization

Comment: I get that part. I'm just not sure if that even makes sense to force your internal users to speak to 2 different boxes. 1 to work as the app and another to have them login.

Comment: But you can do the authentication as a one time thing. once the client is authorized you can keep the key with the client app (e.g. what twitter clients do).

Comment: Okay makes sense... That's one option. I'm not sure if it makes a ton of sense in this case but I'd guess it'd work for that.